# Ember component not rendering string from API call

Tags: ember.js

very new to Ember so I may understand things incorrectly. I have a simple component

```
UserAdmin.OrganizationStringComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
id: -1,
organizationName: function () {
    var id = this.get("id");
    var organizationName = "http://localhost:41109/api/org/" + id;
    return organizationName
}.property("id")});
```

The result if this simple \api call is just a string. I copied the idea from a gravatar component that did something similar with an image. Do I have to write a complete ajax call inside the component to make it fire the call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes

A longer answer, you have a couple options

you can use [Ember.RSVP](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/RSVP.Promise.html) promises to either return a promise, or, after the promise has been fulfilled, return the result

robert ward has a good [screencast](http://eviltrout.com/2014/05/29/emberreddit-screencast.html) on how to do this in more detail. definitely worth a look if you're just starting out, as his information is applicable(ember-cli is a set of build tools built around ember)

you can also use [Ember.$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

what you're doing right now is setting a variable to a string, then returning that string